# My Notes App Disappeared

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

I am using an iPhone 7+ and noticed my Notes application is missing this morning! I keep stuff in there I have trouble remembering so I always save it to my iPhone and iCloud when I add something to my Notes. I have 19 folders in there. When I go to Manage iCloud storage the only selection is to delete. When I open the notes icon there it only gives me information about the notes app. Where’d it go? How do I retrieve it? HELP!

Comment: I suppose you have tried searching for the Notes app?

Comment: I did and it shows it is routed to iCloud, however the app doesn’t show up in iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that it got deleted somehow. Yes Apple now lets you "delete" built-in apps.

...Unless it is hidden. Do a search on your phone for "notes" to make sure it is not installed.

You would re-install a coup[le of different ways. 1) by going to the App Store, searching for "Notes," tap on it and look for the familiar yellow on top of white icon. You can tap on it to make sure that the developer is "Apple"

Then just tap the cloud download icon (the cloud with the downward pointing arrow) and wait for the App to install.

...Or in your search results next to Notes is a "View" button. That will bring it up in the app store. Follow the above directions to install it.

your Notes app is restored.

Comment: Thank you! I re-loaded the app, opened it up and it was empty... then I opened a new folder and it started loading all my old folders, YAY! 

Comment: @Debbi, cool glad to help. AskDifferent etiquette says that if someone provides **the** answer to your question you accept it as the answer so they get "credit" for helping out. It's a kind of "pay it forward -and back-" system. Also drop by whenever you like to ask, answer or comment on anything to feel you know *the* or *a possible* answer to.